# Lubuntu on Ubuntu. Auto choose Lubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, lubuntu

Can I install Lubuntu on Ubuntu and when the PC boots up, it chooses Lubuntu as default?

Comment: Feel free to correct me, but instead of installing 2 different flavours of ubuntu and choosing in grub which to auto-boot, wouldnt it be easier to maintain just 1 ubuntu install which offers both desktop environments (Unity & LXDE and in addition even Gnome and mate if you feel lucky)? This reduces disk-usage and in general simplifies the setup. I am assuming here you are not forced to have 2 seperate installations on that machine.

Comment: In case you want to installations there is as well the method to just tell grub to remember the last option via 'GRUB_DEFAULT=saved' and 'GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true' in /etc/default/grub. You would need to update grub then via  'sudo update-grub'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Grub Customizer

on the "List configuration" tab, move lubuntu to the top,

and on the "General setting" tab, insert 0 Second in "Boot default entry after" option

Comment: inserting 0 second in the option is optional if you need time to choose another OS